# Remove extra bagage from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having an issue to replace `"\r\n        Departing\r\n                  "` with `"Departing"` in javascript.

Please suggest best way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
"\r\n Departing\r\n ".replace(/[^a-z]/gmi,'');
```

g => global
m => multi-line
i => case-insesitive

[^a-z] => chars, a to z, but thanks to case-insensitivity A-Z are not replaced, either.

If numbers might occur in the string, you can prevent them from being replaced pretty easily:

```
"\r\n Departing2\r\n ".replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gmi,'');
```

If all you want to do is remove line-feeds and trim the remaining string:

```
"\r\n Departing2\r\n ".replace(/[\r\n]/gm,'').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
"\r\n We're Departing, too\r\n!".replace(/[\r\n]/gm,'').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
```

Should take care of things for you rather nicely

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
"\r\n Departing\r\n ".trim()
```

Comment: Word of warning: IE <9 doesn't have a trim method, you'll have to augment the prototype: `if (!String.prototype.trim){ String.prototype.trim = function(){ return this.replace(/[\r\n]/g,'').replace(/^\s\s*/,'')).replace(/\s\s*$/,'');};}`

Comment: The question doesn't state if to remove all white spaces, but if that would be the case, .trim() would only remove at the start and end.

Comment: @Mario: there's a space after the line-feed, just before `Departing`, and as the desired result is `'Departing'`, it's a fair assumption to make, IMHO

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I agree, but never the less, I'm still pointing it out for the user to notice in case it's not how we assume =)

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp.

```
str.replace(/\s/g,"");    /*  "\r\n Departing\r\n "(/\s/g,"") = "Departing" */
```

Comment: Shusi, it also removes spaces in between words which i don't want. like , `first name` is replaced by `firstname`.

Comment: @Ramiz-Raja, in that case, my suggestion is what you need: `"\r\n We're Departing, too!\r\n ".replace(/[\r\n]/gm,'').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');` returns: _"We're Departing, too!"_

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = "\r\n Departing\r\n ";
mystring = mystring.replace(/\r\n/g, "");
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxgus/7/)

Comment: The suggested trim method is not to be recommended, it won't filter out unix-style line-feeds (`\n`) and breaks the expected behaviour of removing trailing spaces, too.